# What is the difference between sort.Slice and sort.SliceStable

Tags: go

According to the docs https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Slice, sort.Slice is not guaranteed to be stable. What makes it unstable and when would I look to use sort.SliceStable instead?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability

Comment: "What makes it unstable [?]" Its implementation for large slices (quicksort). "when would I look to use sort.SliceStable instead?" Whenever your slice is presorted to a key you cannot (or don't want to) use as a tiebreaker during sorting. Stable sorting twice, first by key x and then by key y does what people would expect from "sorting a list twice": Afterwards the list is sorted by y with ties resolved by x.

Comment: Thank you for these responses, I was using a different definition of "stable" in that I thought one would likely break for some reason. In this case, I see the difference between what happens when two values are equal in the comparison.

Answer (score 8):

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Stable_sorts

> Stable sorting algorithms maintain the relative order of records with
> equal keys (i.e. values). That is, a sorting algorithm is stable if
> whenever there are two records R and S with the same key and with R
> appearing before S in the original list, R will appear before S in the
> sorted list.